# fullPage.js with wow.js animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, wow.js

I am making my first website with full Page and wow plugins. My problem is that wow animations aren't loaded after page is scrolled down. I tried to add animation class to the div after loading page, but it doesn't work. Any ideas how to do it correctly?
Here is my code initializing plugins

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#fullpage').fullpage({
              'afterLoad': function(anchorLink, index){
                 if(index == '2'){
                    $('#animation_content').addClass('wow lightSpeedIn');
                 }
              },
           });
        });
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you reaching the afterload function?  Can you put a breakpoint there and interrogate index?  How about a fiddle?

Comment: Well, when I put alert('something') in the if statement it works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 4):

Wow.js depends on the `scroll` event.

Fullpage.js doesn't really scroll the page (fires the scroll event) unless you use the option `autoScrolling:false` or `scrollBar:true` as detailed in [the FAQ of fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#jquery-scrolltop-function-doesnt-work).

If you still want to use wow without any of those options, the only solution would be trying to use the callbacks `afterLoad` or `onLeave` of fullpage.js to add the needed classes or data for wow.js to work.

Here's a topic in the fullpage.js github forum about it:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/249

You can also see [my video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=1s) regarding how to create CSS 3 animations by using the fullpage.js state classes.

Answer (score 4):

Use this: scrollBar:true in settings and then in your CSS set

```
body,html{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Then wow.js will work and you wont see that scrollBar you set to true :) MAGIC